# Printing output of command

Tags: rust, command, gtk

I'm using [gtk-rs](https://gtk-rs.org/) to take the value of an input and use it to execute a command with [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool):

```
 input.connect_activate(clone!(@weak window => move |entry| {
    let input_text = entry.text();
    let cmd = format!(
        "xdotool search --onlyvisible --name {} windowactivate",
        input_text
    );

    let output = std::process::Command::new("sh")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg(cmd)
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));

    window.close();
}));
```

I'm getting this compiling error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:66:48
    |
66  |         println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
    |                        ----------------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected slice `[u8]`, found enum `std::option::Option`
    |                        |
    |                        arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected reference `&[u8]`
               found reference `&std::option::Option<ChildStdout>`
note: associated function defined here
   --> /home/alex/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/string.rs:631:12
    |
631 |     pub fn from_utf8_lossy(v: &[u8]) -> Cow<'_, str> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So I tried this:

```
match output.stdout {
    Some(stdout) => {
        println!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout));
    },
    None => {
        println!("No output");
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the same error.

**Update:**

I tried:

```
let output = std::process::Command::new("sh")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg(cmd)
    .output()
    .unwrap();

println!(Output: "{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
```

But nothing is being printed:

```
Output:
```

Full code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea4431b73191c132f4392378cce13604

Comment: You probably want to use [`.output()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.output) instead of `spawn`

Comment: @PitaJ I tried that. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I believe PitaJ is right, are you sure your xdotool command actually writes anything to stdout? Check stderr and/or check your xdotool command manually in a shell.

Comment: What @PitaJ suggested seems like the correct solution. You might be getting an error, which will only show up on `.stderr` instead of `.stdout`. Checking `output.status.success()` also seems like a good way to know what's going on.

Comment: @JoãoHaas `output.status` logs `exit status: 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments and docs, I managed to print the command with:

```
println!("stdout: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout));
println!("stderr: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr));
```

But I had to do: `xdotool search --onlyvisible --name {}` because `xdotool search --onlyvisible --name {} windowactivate` prints nothing.